# Proving the surface is minimum for a certain volume

Tags: area, volume

I have the following problem. I want to find the function whose revolution volume for a certain volume gives the minimum area. I have read that it is the hyperbola but I don't know how to prove it.

I have the following. For a function $f(x)$, we have that the volume of its revolution solid is

$$\int _a ^b \pi f(x) ^2 dx$$

The area will be

$$\int _a ^b 2 \pi f(x) dx + \pi f(a)^2 + \pi f(b) ^2$$

In the formula of the area we add at the end the area of the circles at the end of the solid.

If I take the quotient, I should optimize it for a minimum value, but I get stuck there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The surface area of the rotational part is $2\pi \int_a^b f(x)\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}\>dx$.